# How to rectify js files problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
  {{{body}}}
    <script src="/bundles/libscripts.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/vendorscripts.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jquery-steps/jquery.steps.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/jvectormap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/sparkline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/knob.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/mainscripts.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pages/charts/jquery-knob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pages/forms/form-validation.js"></script>

in app.js i have included
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
where in above js files are located in public folder
```

These js files are at the end of Layout.hbs in nodejs project
They halt my project once i try to submit form which is rendered in {{body}}
I Commented the above js files in layout and eveything worked fine
I need help to handle this situation. Aprt form node js file these js files in layout are may be overriding thos se js files thus cauing halt.
How to handle this situation